# Vue router-link param undefined in nested loop

Tags: loops, vue.js, bind, vue-router

I have a loop inside another loop.

The `videos.id` is undefined in the `<router-link>` but is rendered just fine otherwise..

```
    <ul>
      <li v-for="category in categories" :key="category.id">
       {{category.name}}
        <div v-for="videos in category.videos" :key="videos.id">
           <router-link v-bind:to="/video-player/ + videos.id"> {{videos.id}}  {{videos.name}}</router-link>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Hi @Nate

I've made a codepen with my structure and template

[link](https://codepen.io/cwerner/pen/mdyjLBv)

Can you give an example of how the use the computed property from this data structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your codepen: https://codepen.io/cwerner/pen/mdyjLBv

It is showing videos.id as undefined because this data doesn't exist:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Category",
    videos: [
      {
        name: "Video1"
      },
      {
        name: "Video 2",
      }
    ],
  }
```

There is only an id for category, so you must add id's in the video objects too:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Category",
    videos: [
      {
        name: "Video1",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Video 2",
        id: 2
      }
    ],
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Content of binded property has to be valid JS expression. `/video-player/ + videos.id` is not valid JS expression. Change it to `v-bind:to="'/video-player/' + videos.id"`